# Is it possible to Migrate from Windows Server 2003 Standard to Windows Server 2012 Essentials?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, essentials-2012-r2

I've done a bunch of searching and can't find a definitive answer to whether it's possible to migrate from an existing Windows Server 2003 R2 (standard edition) domain controller, to a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials domain controller (on new hardware).

Microsoft don't list it as one of their migration scenarios on Technet, but they don't explicitly say it's not possible either.

I found one forum thread that suggested it was not possible, but other articles I've seen make it sound like it is possible.

Can anyone say whether a migration from 2003 standard to 2012 essentials will work? It may be worth mentioning that the 2003 standard is 32 bit (I've read that can require extra steps to migrate active directory in some cases).

Also, I would (naturally) be retiring the 2003 domain controller after the migration.

Comment: Windows 2012 Essentials it's Windows 2003 SBS successor so officially only migration from previous versions of Windows Server SBS/Essentials line (2003 SBS, 2008 SBS/Foundation, 2011 SBS/Essentials) is supported (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200183.aspx). 
Anyway you can try to migrate from 2003 Standard in a way described for migration from 2003 SBS

Comment: Hi Sergey, So you're certain that Microsoft _only_ officially support migrations from previous SBS editions of Windows Server? That leaves the question of whether a migration will work (unofficially) from a Standard edition of Windows Server 2003. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test as I had similar question and needed to find out for myself (for a client) if I could upgrade Windows 2003 to Windows 2016 Essentials.  It is not officially documented anywhere, but did a test using a bare bones Windows 2003 Std server (not even any updates) and a trial Windows 2016 Essentials version.  Actually both were in trial mode.

IF DOING THIS ON A PRODUCTION SERVER, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.  MAKE BACKUPS, etc.
This is just a quick rundown and by no means a complete step by step. On VM’s or test PC, whatever floats your boat. I also assume you will have experience with migrating domains.

1. Made the Windows 2003 Std server AD, DNS, etc, and added some users and login scripts.  Basic stuff. Gave it a Static IP.
2. Raised its Domain AND Forest Functional Level to Windows 2003.
3. When installing the Windows 2016 Essentials server on my test PC, I made sure NOT to use the Essentials Wizard at all.  Went into the Add Remove wizard and removed the Essentials Experience (you could I suppose re-install this later after all is said and done, but for my purposes, will not need it.) It will require a reboot.  NOTE: To get rid of the Essentials Wizard from constantly nagging you on reboot, open the Registry on the 2016 server and go HKLM\software\Microsoft\windows\currentversion\run and delete the Essentials Wizard exe, or back it up and then delete, etc.
4. Rename the server in the Server Manager\Local Machine.
5. Give it a static IP and let the DNS point to the 2003 DC.
6. Add the 2016 Essentials server to the 2003 domain as a member server. It will need a reboot.
7. Once it’s all rebooted and you logged into the 2003 AD domain, proceed with creating the 2016 Essentials server as a domain server by following the usual Microsoft best practices. (This is a pretty good step by step: https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2016/10/prepare-active-directory-windows-server-2016-dc-adprep/)
8. Once the 2016 Essentials server is now the DC and DNS, etc, you need to ensure the Operations Masters Roles are NOT using the old 2003 Std server, and you also need to make sure the old 2003 Std server is NOT a Global catalog server.
9. Once step 8 is done, run a dcpromo /adv on the 2003 Std server and let it demote itself to a member server.
10. Ensure the DNS on the 2016 Essentials Network adapter now only has itself as the DNS server.  It will likely show both itself and the old 2003 STD server as DNS servers.
11. Once that’s completed, check your DNS on the 2016 Essentials server to ensure the Sites and any A records do not point anymore to the old 2003 Std server. Also, check your Active Directory Sites and Services, Default First Site Name and Servers, and then delete the old 2003 Std there.

That did it for me.  No issues so far, although this is a test scenario.  But it can be done in my opinion.  If anyone has found otherwise, please let us know.